# ios swift - scroll view over image doesn't scroll

Tags: ios, scrollview

I want to have a background image that does not move and have a scrollview over it that allows users to scroll through content while the back image remaining static.

I have tried adding an image to my view and then after a scroll view over it but I'm unable to scroll.

I'm trying to achieve an effect similar to this:

[image]

Am I on the right path to achieving this?

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: @anhtu there's no code when I'm testing with ib. Thanks for your input

Comment: are you using autolayout ?

Comment: Yes. Can you confirm that that's a scrollview over an image and not a tableview?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set contentSize for UIScrollView. ContentSize has to greater than frame size.